# Migrating from a Shared Database to Heroku Postgres /

Tags: heroku

ON MAC OS X 1.7.2

I tried following the instructions https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/migrating-from-shared-database-to-heroku-postgres

So I tried running the command on my-app:

```
$ heroku addons:add heroku-postgresql:dev -a my-app
-----> Adding heroku-postgresql:dev to test-biowatts... failed
 !     You're running an outdated version of the Heroku gem/toolbelt that cannot perform the requested action. Please update your client and try again.
```

So I tried to update Heroku

```
$ heroku update
 !   update is not a heroku command. See 'heroku help'.
```

Where

```
$ heroku version
heroku-gem/2.4.0
```

QUESTION UPDATE 1 - Heroku update now gives a different message

```
$ heroku update
 !    `heroku update` is only available from Heroku Toolbelt.
 !    Download and install from https://toolbelt.heroku.com
```

so I downloaded and installed toolbelt but the heroku update still gives the same message

QUESTION UPDATE 2 - Removed heroku installed TOOLBELT - RESOLVED

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/heroku 
sudo rm -rf /usr/bin/heroku
gem uninstall heroku
```

then installed https://toolbelt.heroku.com/

Restarted terminal

AND IT WORKED!

Cheers,

joel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried gem update heroku?

If you are using Mac OSX mountain lion. Maybe you should better use heroku toolbelt. I had almost same issue, and it fixed after I installed Heroku toolbelt.

Comment: oh that's what I am trying to do actually. I downloaded that package and installed, but the heroku update command still doesn't work. I must be missing something

Comment: Updated the problem description. I am on Mac OS X 1.7.2 (Lion)

Comment: try this, rm -rf /usr/local/heroku
rm -rf /usr/bin/heroku for deleting old toolbelt and gem uninstall heroku. after that reinstall heroku toolbelt.try heroku update again.

Comment: still fails. How did you install toolbelt. I am downloading from the the website and installing the package. Is there a command line for that. Also I am using RVM.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14965/discussion-between-joelmaranhao-and-atsuhiro-teshima)

Comment: I also installed toolbelt from the web site. and did exact the same way I commented above. the difference is I'm using rbenv not RVM.